# append javascript array data into table td

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

each id was repeating twice..i don't want to repeat each id

```js
let t_p_data = [
    {
        id: 11001
    },
    {
        id: 11002
    },
];
let paymentsData = $('.payments-data');
paymentsList = paymentsData.innerHTML;
for (i=0; i<t_p_data.length; i++) {
    for (let p_data of t_p_data) {
        paymentsList += ` <tr><td>${p_data.id}</td></tr>  ` }
}paymentsData.append(paymentsList);
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tbody class="payments-data"></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need 2 loops? Just remove one of them

```js
let t_p_data = [
    {
        id: 11001
    },
    {
        id: 11002
    },
];
let paymentsData = $('.payments-data');
paymentsList = '';

for (let p_data of t_p_data) {
  paymentsList += ` <tr><td>${p_data.id}</td></tr>  ` 
}
paymentsData.append(paymentsList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tbody class="payments-data"></tbody></table>
```

Comment: `paymentsList =paymentsData.innerHTML` doesn't make sense ...a jQuery object has no `innerHTML`

Comment: You'r right. I copied it from the question and didn't realise it didn't make sense. Since the data is already being appended, what the op wanted to achieve will happen regardless of the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0; i<t_p_data.length; i++) {

    for (let p_data of **t_p_data[i]**) {

        paymentsList += ` <tr><td>${p_data.id}</td></tr>  ` }
}paymentsData.append(paymentsList);
```

In the for..of loop you are referring to the array, so it's printing twice the id value for each element. If you only need to print .id property, remove one of the loops.